# reading in a file and CryptUnprotectData in C

Tags: c, winapi

I have the following problem, I want to read in an encrypted file from my computer and just put to the command console what it says.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    DATA_BLOB encr;
    DATA_BLOB decr;
    char c;
    int i;
    FILE *fp = fopen("some data", "rb");
    encr.cbData = 1;
    fseek(fp, 20L, SEEK_SET);
    for (i = 0; i < 60; i++){
        c = fgetc(fp);
        encr.pbData = (BYTE*)c;
        printf("%c", c);
        CryptUnprotectData(&encr, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &decr)
        printf("%s", decr.pbData);
        encr.pbData = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Somehow this doesn't work and I don't know how to get the output.

Comment: Can you please improve what you mean by "somehow this doesnt work"? Does not compile, crashes, gives no output, gives wrong output, what?

Comment: `encr.pbData = (BYTE*)c;` looks suspicious because `c` is a byte not a byte pointer.

Comment: `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char` for good reasons! Read the documentation of the functions you use. And always use error checking.

Comment: Have you seen this [example program](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382377(v=vs.85).aspx) for using `CryptUnprotectData`? Aside: good old MS - it has `void main()`!

Comment: You have to 'respect' encryption libraries that pass "*Reserved*" pointers to the algorithms for which nothing is published and the source unavailable...

Comment: @David, there's nothing mysterious here, the documentation clearly states "reserved for future use".  If and when a later version of the API uses the argument, the documentation will be updated accordingly.  At the moment it does nothing.

Comment: OK, If you can't check under the hood, do you really know it's just "reserved for future use", or is that just something you've decided you can take on faith? If I'm a developer and I have to represent that there are no backdoors and no possibility of encryption compromise, do I really know that nothing is being the door "reserved for future use." Surely if the NSA had a magic number it could pass, M$ would have listed that on the msdn page, right?

Comment: [Long comment deleted; there's little point in arguing.]  Future readers should simply note that there is nothing inherently suspicious about a reserved parameter, and that it would be very easy to implement a back door without one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't decrypt byte by byte. You have to read the whole thing into a buffer and then pass it all to `CryptUnprotectData()`. When you originally called `CryptProtectData()` it told you what the size of the output was. That's the size of the buffer you should decrypt all at once.

Assuming your buffer is actually 60 bytes and in the 20 offset, your code should look something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  BYTE buffer[60];
  DATA_BLOB encr;
  DATA_BLOB decr;
  char c;
  int i;
  FILE *fp = fopen("some data", "rb"); // TODO check return value
  encr.cbData = 1;
  encr.pbData = buffer;
  fseek(fp, 20L, SEEK_SET); // TODO check return value
  fread(buffer, 60, 1, fp); // TODO check return value
  CryptUnprotectData(&encr, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &decr); // TODO check return value
  printf("%s", decr.pbData);
  return 0;
}
```